# How to use overloaded operator== to check if 2d point and 3d point are identical in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to check wether my 2d point and 3d points are identical using operator== that returns true if they are.
How can I implement that?
Do I need to add overloaded operator into both classes or what?
How to compare 2 arguments x and y?
My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point2D {
public:
    Point2D();
//  ~Point2D();
    void SetX(double x);
    void SetY(double y);
    double GetX();
    double GetY();

    
protected:
    double m_x, m_y;
};
class Point3D :Point2D {
public:
    Point3D() :Point2D() { m_z = 0.0; };
protected:
    double m_z;
};
Point2D::Point2D() {
    m_x = 0.0;
    m_y = 0.0;
}

void Point2D::SetX(double x) {
    m_x = x;
}
void Point2D::SetY(double y) {
    m_y = y;
}
double Point2D::GetX() {
    return m_x;
}
double Point2D::GetY() {
    return m_y;
}

int main() {
    Point2D T;

    cout << T.GetX() << " " << T.GetX() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define in what situration "my 2d point and 3d points are identical" first. Then implement that.

Comment: If their x and y coordinates are same, they are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably want public inheritance:

```
class Point3D : public Point2D {
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Once you have that, you can rely on polymorphism to handle things for you and only implement comparison operator for `Point2D`:

```
// the arguments should be const, but your classes are not const correct
bool operator== (/*const*/ Point2D& lhs, /*const*/ Point2D& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetX() == rhs.GetX() && lhs.GetY() == rhs.GetY();
}

int main() {
    Point2D p2;
    Point3D p3;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (p2 == p3);
}
```

You can further improve it by making your functions `const`:

```
class Point2D {
public:
    Point2D();
    void SetX(double x);
    void SetY(double y);
    double GetX() const; //here
    double GetY() const; //here

protected:
    double m_x, m_y;
};

double Point2D::GetX() const { //and here
    return m_x;
}
double Point2D::GetY() const { //and here
    return m_y;
}

//now you can pass arguments by const reference, no accidental modifications in the operator
bool operator== (const Point2D& lhs, const Point2D& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetX() == rhs.GetX() && lhs.GetY() == rhs.GetY();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted to do. I did wanted public inheritance but I forgot to put it. 
I did not know how to make that operator but everything is clearer to me now. Thank you a lot sir!